# Returning a reference to a string object, error: invalid initialization of reference of type âconst string&. c++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, return

I am getting

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type âconst string& {aka const std::basic_string<char>&}â from expression of type âstd::string* const {aka std::basic_string<char>* const}â
```

I have 4 files in total, **parking.h**, **parking.cpp**, **printPark.cpp**, and **main.cpp**

This is what I am doing,

```
//parking.h
Class Parking {
    string location;
    int cost;

   public:
    void  set(const std::string &loc, int num);
    const std::string& getLocName() const();

}
```

.

```
//parking.cpp
void  Parking::set(const std::string &loc, int num) {
   //location = new string;
   location = loc;

   cost = num;
}

// needs to return a reference to a string object
const std::string& Parking::getLocName() const() {

   return location;  
}
```

My printPark.cpp uses the Parking's getLocName(), to just print to screen. and it dynamically allocates memory for a parking object, and sets it with user input from file into a string variable.

```
//printPark.cpp

//if parking info is in parking.dat load it.

string a, b;
int num =5;

ifstream f(filename);
getline(f, a, '\n');
getline(f, b, '\n');

parking = new Parking[2];

parking[0].set(a,num);
parking[1].set(b, num);
```

Comment: a `std::string **` is not a `std::string&`. If you think they are, you need to learn what a *reference* is.

Comment: um, so return *location;? that works but i was not sure. Also can u recomend a good website where i can learn about reference. thanks

Comment: Honestly, there is no reason I can see to dynamic-allocate that member in the first place. `std::string` already manages its content dynamically. Just make the member `std::string`, initialize it (and `cost`) in the constructor *initializer list*, and `return location;` in your getter. Many good things C++-related [**can be read about here**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language).

Comment: @user2387963 Thatd work. What you should really do is make `location` not a pointer, and then just `return location;`.

Comment: thanks, but when i remove the pointer, i get Segmentation fault. code updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing references with addresses (they're not the same; placement of `&` is critical).

To be honest, you likely have zero need to dynamic allocate that member in the first place, as `std::string` manages its content dynamically already.

```
//parking.h
class Parking 
{
    std::string location;
    int cost;

public:
    // default constructor
    Parking() : cost()
    {
    }

    // parameterized constructor
    Parking(const std::string& loc, int num)
        : location(loc), cost(num)
    {
    }

    void set(const std::string &loc, int num)
    {
        location = loc;
        cost = num
    }

    const std::string& getLocName() const
    {
        return location;
    }
};
```

Doing this also makes `Parking` copyable. and assignable, without having to write a custom copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor to comply with the [**Rule of Three**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) (which you may want to read about regardless, as its important).

Comment: after debugging, i am getting seg fault at >location = loc;

Comment: @user2387963 Entirely unrelated to the original question. That would be a problem with the *caller* side, not this. Look again (carefully) at this code. Your code looks right now, so the *source* string your passing is likely the problem (perhaps you implicitly passing a `char*` that isn't determinate).

Comment: yeah i know, but i was getting seg fault. so made it a pointer. the caller has Parking parking;  parking.set(loc , number)   loc is a string.

Comment: Then post the code from the caller side as well (**in the question**), and include the mechanism for how the source string `loc` is created before being passed in to `set()`, as I feel it will be important. And seriously consider opening a different question, as again, that issue is not related to this one. The code in this answer (and now your post above) is correct. When you say "My main dynamically allocates memory for a parking object..." I pray you're not using `malloc`. You should be using `new`. So post the code in `main.cpp`

Comment: sorry my main is printPark.cpp.

Comment: @user2387963 that won't even compile, much less run to a segfault. `parking` isn't declared anywhere, and if it were a pointer-type, you would use `parking->` or `(*parking).` or `parking[0].` to access the first member, not `parking.`. I'm late for a meeting, so I gotta run. I'll check back. **Seriously** open a new question. You're now in code utterly unrelated to the original question answered above.

Comment: @user2387963 [**see it live**](http://ideone.com/feI9sS). Note file system IO isn't allowed on ideone.com, so I used a string stream, but the premise is the same.